# Mirror flip not working

Tags: animation

https://gyazo.com/418be66571a2d28978515c3095f17450

It matches.

They are all the same

[image: They are all the same]

[image: They are all the same]

Comment: Hello and welcome. Could you edit your post and [upload all image into the message](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)?

Answer (score 0):

@ItsRay, it looks like you copied then inverse-pasted, but as long as you don't press <kbd>i</kbd> to insert keyframes, no keyframe, and therefore no pose, will be saved, unless you've activated the *Automatic Keyframe Insertion* button in the *Timeline* header bar, which would allow to automatically create the new keyframes, but I don't think you've activated it.